# Casting double int pointer to a regular 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have this global enum and a 3D array:

```
enum place { SCISSORS, DRILL, BENDING_MACHINE, WELDER, PAINT_SHOP, SCREWDRIVER, MILLING_CUTTER };

const int placeRecipeIndexes[_PLACE_COUNT][_PHASE_COUNT][TOOLS_REPEAT_COUNT] = {
        [SCISSORS] = {{0, EMPTY}, {1, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}},
        [DRILL] = {{1, 4}, {0, 3}, {1, 3}},
        [BENDING_MACHINE] = {{2, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}},
        [WELDER] = {{3, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}},
        [PAINT_SHOP] = {{5, EMPTY}, {4, EMPTY}, {5, EMPTY}},
        [SCREWDRIVER] = {{EMPTY, EMPTY}, {5, EMPTY}, {2, EMPTY}},
        [MILLING_CUTTER] = {{EMPTY, EMPTY}, {2, EMPTY}, {0, 4}}
};
```

and I need a pointer (or possibly a copy) which points to a particular 2D sub-array of `placeRecipeIndexes` which means that by pointing to `placeRecipeIndexes[0]`, I would have a 2D array looking like this:

`{{0, EMPTY}, {1, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}}`.

At first, I tried it without a pointer: `const int indexes[_PHASE_COUNT][TOOLS_REPEAT_COUNT] = toolsIndexes[idx];` but it gave me:

*Array initializer must be an initializer list.*

so I tried to do it like this:

`const int **indexes = (const int **) toolsIndexes[idx];`

but I can't access the `indexes` array positions because they're presumably empty - I'm getting `SIGSEV`.

I thought that this should definitely work. Am I missing something important here?

MRE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EMPTY -1

enum place { SCISSORS, DRILL, BENDING_MACHINE, WELDER, PAINT_SHOP, SCREWDRIVER, MILLING_CUTTER };

const int placeRecipeIndexes[7][3][2] = {
        [SCISSORS] = {{0, EMPTY}, {1, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}},
        [DRILL] = {{1, 4}, {0, 3}, {1, 3}},
        [BENDING_MACHINE] = {{2, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}},
        [WELDER] = {{3, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}, {EMPTY, EMPTY}},
        [PAINT_SHOP] = {{5, EMPTY}, {4, EMPTY}, {5, EMPTY}},
        [SCREWDRIVER] = {{EMPTY, EMPTY}, {5, EMPTY}, {2, EMPTY}},
        [MILLING_CUTTER] = {{EMPTY, EMPTY}, {2, EMPTY}, {0, 4}}
};

int main() {
    const int **indexes = (const int **) placeRecipeIndexes[0];

    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("{%d, ", indexes[i][0]);
        if (i != 2) {
            printf("%d}, ", indexes[i][1]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d}", indexes[i][1]);
        }
    }
    printf("}\n");

    // The output should be: {{0, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @user3629249 Added.

Comment: @tomashauser `(const int **) placeRecipeIndexes[0];` This cast is wrong because the type of  `placeRecipeIndexes[0]` is `int[3][2]` which can decay to `int (*)[2]` but not `int **`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
    const int **indexes = (const int **) placeRecipeIndexes[0];
```

with:

```
    const int (*indexes)[2] = placeRecipeIndexes[0];     // C
```

or:

```
    const int (&indexes)[3][2] = placeRecipeIndexes[0];  // C++
```

For verification, the following check out (in C++):

```
static_assert(&indexes[0][0] == &placeRecipeIndexes[0][0][0]);
static_assert(&indexes[2][1] == &placeRecipeIndexes[0][2][1]);
```

Comment: I'm getting `error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘&’ token`.

Comment: @tomashauser It's compiling fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/d7Pqfo).

Comment: Well I'm using `-std=c99` - it may be that.

Comment: @tomashauser Updated the answer for C, verified [here](https://godbolt.org/z/o5Mjh4).

Comment: Great, it works now. Funny thing is that I was trying this but without the brackets.